# adding-migration DataAnnotations doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have made a small MVC project and was trying to implement validation inside it.
following this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

I made changes in my student table class.

and then tried adding the migration as it says but it says

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Bittu2'.
>   (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from
>   Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

I tried Enabling-Migrations and running the code but it now says

> Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created
>   using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be
>   obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing
>   DbCompiledModel.

I have used databasefirst approach

Please tell what to do?

Comment: As you defined you have used `Db-First` approach so it doesn't support the migrations. migration only supported in `Code-First` not another approaches.

Comment: Consider using ViewModels and add your validation there. No migrations or database updates needed.

Comment: You want to reverse engineer the db first solution to code first. Help can be found [here](http://devgush.com/2014/02/24/migrating-a-project-from-database-first-to-code-first/)

Comment: What if I don't want to?
Any other way to add validation on Model attributes?

Comment: @SteveGreene I haven't studies ViewModels... Is there any other way?

Comment: There is always another way. If you want to stick with database first, then you should create partial classes for your validation annotations so they are not lost when you regenerate. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation).